# How do I close a object with the curve modifier applied to it?

Tags: objects, bezier-curves, path

I was wondering if there was a way to connect the two end points of this strap I made on blender.

I can't seem to get an even fit.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select one end of the curve, then the second end (holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>) and press <kbd>F</kbd> button. It'll connect two ends.
[image]

Now choose the merged end, select the handle and press <kbd>S</kbd>. Hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to precisely match two ends of the mesh.
[image]
[image]

This may although change a shape of a curve a bit. You may use the other method, which leaves the curve's shape as it is. First select the mesh, enter the *Edit Mode* and enable the ***'use the modifier while in edit mode'*** option.
[image]

Now scale the mesh along the desired axis to match its ends precisely.
[image]

You may also select the *Curve*, then go to the *Curve Data* header and check the ***Stretch*** and ***Bounds Clamp*** checkboxes in the *Shape* panel.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just make the curve cyclic:
[image]
[image]
This will link your start and end points

Comment: Hm when I went to go do it I noticed that it was already on cyclic. However, I played around with the setting on the Active Spline panel and all I did was bump up the Order option that isn't on your screen shot but it it's above Resolution in mine! Thank you for leading me to the right location (:

Comment: order is found on Nurbs curves, i used bezier. cyclic option is supposed to work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle Cyclic with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.